# Set list as keys in dict with unknown number of list elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there any way to set nested keys based on a list?
I have the following code:

```
def setDictKeys (dict, atKey, keysList):
    for key in keysList:
        dict[atKey][key] = {}
```

And by calling

```
setDictKeys(dict, ["a", "b"], someKeysList)
```

I want the dictionary to look like this:

```
dict["a"]["b"]["key from someKeysList"] = {}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `list` can not be set as the key of the dictionary. You can check `defaultdict` from `collections` package and define the default type as dict. For nested case also, you'll need to again set new defaultdict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a loop to iterate the individual keys in `atKey` and dive "deeper" into the nested dict.

```
def setDictKeys (d, atKey, keysList):
    for key in atKey:
        d = d.setdefault(key, {})
    for key in keysList:
        d[key] = {}

d = {}
setDictKeys(d, ["a", "b"], ["some", "Keys", "List"])
# {'a': {'b': {'some': {}, 'Keys': {}, 'List': {}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way for the particular question

```
def fun(d,atkey,listofkeys):
    d[atkey[0]]={atkey[1]:{}}
    for i in listofkeys:
        d[atkey[0]][atkey[1]][i] = {}
    return d
print(fun({'1':'h999'},['a','b'],['hi','hello','abcd','a','b']))
```

Comment: "This particular question" is asking about an "unknown number of list elements", though.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a functional solution using `collections.defaultdict`. Depending on your use case you may not need to instantiate children dictionaries manually. You can just use a nested `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import getitem
from functools import reduce

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
d = tree()

def setDictKeys(dataDict, atKey, keysList):
    reduce(getitem, atKey, dataDict).update({i: {} for i in keysList})

setDictKeys(d, ['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3])

print(d)

defaultdict({'a': defaultdict({'b': defaultdict({1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}})})})
```